# Identifying and Non-identifying Relationship Between Tables(Entities)

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I have created my own entities with attributes and key constraints, and when I generated my EER Diagram, I realized that every relationship I have is non-identifying.

Does anyone know if it is okay to have many tables with only non-identifying relationship?

Comment: One-to-many relationships between independent entities are non-identifying relationships.

Comment: Thank you for replying to my post! I am wondering if it is okay to have Eg 12 tables in an EER diagram, all connected by ONLY non-identifying relationship? Or does an EER diagram with only non-identifying relationships means that it is wrong or should be amended etc?

Comment: Seems to me you have a surrogate key (identity/autonum) on each table then.   It's not a design problem in my mind.  Though you have a data for no other purpose than to identify a unique record.  Space wise you're taking up more space than needed; though likely for a slight performance gain

Comment: If all of the relationships are one-to-many between independent entities then all of them will be non-identifying relationships.